# Tiling automation of landsat 8 images?

Tags: landsat-8, tiling

I have a grid (can be in shapefile and can be also in coordinates) and I need to know how can I create tilings with it to Landsat 8 images (16 bit images), selecting the output tile size, the overlap.

I have tried with MapTiler but it doesn't work with that images (16bit) and also with gdal2tiles.

I tried installing GeoTools or SimpleTiles but I couldn't and I don't know if it's an easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

`gdal_translate with -co "TILED=YES"` should work for your task

Answer (score 1):

The landsat must be preprocessed before rendering, during the preprocessing you can probably convert to 8bit GeoTiff anyway.

Then rendering of large areas can be easily done with http://www.maptiler.com/

For tips how to process the landsat8 see:

https://gist.github.com/klokan/8832708
https://www.mapbox.com/blog/processing-landsat-8/

or

http://www.geosage.com/highview/features_landsat8.html